# Is there a way to open a file through python and activate code after it's closed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a background running file, and I want the file to open a file, wait for its termination and activate some code after.
I want to open the file in the path `/../foo.exe`.
Any help appreciated.

I tried `process = subprocess.Popen([f"start {os.path.dirname(__file__)}foo.exe"])`
But I got the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ORI\Desktop\everything\General stuff\EasyRP-windows\configs\background.py", line 5, in <module>
    process = subprocess.Popen([f"start {os.path.dirname(__file__)}foo.exe"]) #\\..\\easyrp.exe"
  File "C:\Users\ORI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\ORI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Is the file being closed by your script, or by some other program?

Comment: I tried doing
`process = subprocess.Popen([f"start {os.path.dirname(__file__)}foo.exe"])'
but i got an error message. @JohnGordon

Comment: @JohnGordon the file is being closed manually, by pressing the x button of the program.

Comment: If you got an error message from the popen command, show it to us.  Telling us "I got an error message" isn't very helpful.

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry, edited the post to have the error.

Comment: It may be better to say that you want to execute a program and wait for its termination.

Comment: @nojif according to that error, you're just specifying the file path incorrectly.

Comment: you need an extra slash `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)}, "foo.exe"`

Comment: You're telling popen to run a command that is literally named `start foo.exe`, which of course doesn't exist.  You need to pass a list of each separate argument: `Popen(["start", "foo.exe"])`

Comment: @JohnGordon tried it, still getting the same error. I moved that the file I'm trying to access is in the same folder too, with no success.